# Sequence generator with aggregator

Tags: informatica

Data is being passed through an aggregator transformation and grouped by customer account number to ensure I have distinct values. This is then passed to an expression transformation. I have a sequence generator transformation linked to the expression transformation - it never touches the aggregator. A variable in the expression is populated with the sequence number.

The problem I am running into is that the variable is coming up with a value in excess of the sequence number - e.g if there are 499 rows, the value of the variable is 501. It's as though the value assigned to the variable is ignoring the grouping and returning a non-distinct count.

Any idea what's happening here?

edit: More info on how this is being done. (Can't screenshot as it's too big.)

Flow 1 takes a list of account numbers, service numbers and destination systems and uses a router to sort them into flat files by destination system.

```
123456|0299999999|SYSA
123456|0299999999|SYSB
123457|0299999998|SYSA
123457|0299999998|SYSB
123457|0299999997|SYSA
123457|0299999997|SYSB
```

Some systems don't want the service number and some do. For those that do, it's a simple exercise of routing them through an expression transformation to set the variable using the sequence number. So the required output for SYSA would look like:

```
123456|0299999999|SYSA
123457|0299999998|SYSA
123457|0299999997|SYSA
```

And the expression transformation sets the variable using:

```
SETVARIABLE($$SYSA, SEQUENCE_NO)
```

In a second flow, I construct header and trailer files. For the trailer record count, I simply output the current value of `$$SYSA` like so:

```
SETVARIABLE($$SYSA, NULL)
```

I use Target Load Plan to execute the second flow only after the first completes.

I can demonstrate that using the variable in this way works, because the workflow outputs the correct values every time - I can alter the source datato increase or decrease the number of rows, and the value output for `$$SYSA` in the second flow is correct the first time (i.e it can't be a persisted value).

Where this is falling down is when the destination system only wants distinct account numbers and no service numbers. The required output for SYSB would be:

```
123456|SYSB
123457|SYSB
```

i.e the third row for SYSB is discarded because the account number is not unique. I'm trying to achieve this by putting an aggregator between the router and the expression, and grouping by the account number. However the `$$SYSB` variable isn't being assigned correctly in this case.

Comment: did you check how many records are coming out of aggregator? Maybe your group by is not working as you expected.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. How many rows pass through the expression? What is the sequence of numbers you get assigned from the sequence generator? Maybe go through it with the debugger to see what's happening. Note that the sequence generator always caches multiple numbers, so even if you don't use the numbers, they are never returned by the sequence generator again.

Comment: @Samik I'm getting 499 rows out of the aggregator which is as expected. There are 501 rows going into it, with two account numbers which are repeated once each (so 499 distinct account numbers).

Comment: @socken23 The sequence of numbers is 1-499 inclusive. The variable is populated within the expression, so as each row is written the variable is updated to the current sequence number. The sequence number is only 499 max, so I don't understand how the variable is 501.

Comment: Are you doing any calculation in the variable expression or using the sequence generator value directly? I am not sure why you need a variable.

Comment: @Samik I'm not doing any calculation - it's literally `SETVARIABLE($$X, SEQUENCENO)`. I'm using it later in a separate flow to construct a trailer file.

Comment: Okay, but mapping variables are set at the end of the session. You will not be able to use the value in another flow. In the other flow, the variable will return the value set in the previous run.

Comment: It would help if you could post some screenshot. Please also explain what do you need the variable value for - my guess is you shouldn't be using mapping variables at all. As Samik noted, these are set after mapping run is complete and might be tricky.

Comment: @Samik added detail to my question.

Comment: Well, something I've done seems to have fixed it - not sure what it was but I've tested and retested and it's working as expected. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

It appears Informatica was only updating the value of the variable if it is higher than the persistent value stored in the repository. So if a successful run persists a value of 501 to the repository, that value is picked up again at the start of the next run and it's only overridden if the new value is higher. I worked around it by declaring a starting value of 0 in the parameter file.